# "Уверяю" - это вводное слово?

Tags: запятые

"Уверяю" - это вводное слово? Если да, то когда оно им является? И правильно ли я сделал, что взял слово "уверяю" в кавычки? Просто мой друг мне доказывает, что они здесь не нужны.

Answer (score 1):

> И правильно ли я сделал, что взял слово "уверяю" в кавычки?

Да, это естественное оформление текста. Здесь же имеется в виду не действие, а слово, это действие обозначающее.

> "Уверяю" - это вводное слово?

Обычно - нет. Но можно представить (в разговорном стиле особенно) фразу типа ***"Он же, уверяю, совершенно безобидный человек!"*** Тут "уверяю - вводное.

> Если да, то когда оно им является?

Как всегда, вводным является слово или сочетание, не являющееся членом предложения, характеризующее не само действие, а отношение к нему, источник информации, её достоверность и так далее. 
Для проверки можно попытаться изъять анализируемое слово из предложения - грамматика не должна пострадать, а общий смысл сохраниться.

Не буду я примеры из классики искать... Проще сконструировать по ситуации.

***"Я вас уверяю, что он уже выехал к нам"*** - здесь член предложения, сказуемое.
***"Он уже, уверяю, выехал к нам"*** - вводное.

Не знаю, какие тут могут быть трудности, вызвавшие ваш вопрос.